# Retrieving an array of classes in a directory

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony's `ClassMapGenerator` to get an array of all classes inside a directory:

```
ClassMapGenerator::createMap(__DIR__ . '/Generators')
```

This works just fine - but the `ClassMapGenerator` class was deprecated in Symfony 3.3, and completely removed in symfony 4.

Since we've just performed an upgrade to Symfony 4, this code no longer works.

I've read [this article](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-deprecated-the-classloader-component) that explains why it was removed, but doesn't offer any alternatives.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this by replacing the Symfony import with Composer's ClassMapGenerator.

```
use Composer\Autoload\ClassMapGenerator;
```

The syntax is exactly the same